# How would you turn that into a conditional sentence?

Tags: conditional-constructions

> I'm not wealthy enough to buy a Rolls-Royce.

If this statement has to be conditional, would it be

> If I were wealthy enough, I would buy a Rolls-Royce.

or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct.

You're basically turning out the present-real statement into an unreal present situation. You can also leave the *if*-clause at the end and leave out the comma:

> *I'd buy a Rolls-Royce if I were wealthy enough.*